# Drupal how to set up path for library and include files

Tags: drupal, include-path

In Drupal 7, I am writing PHP from inside the Front Page module, say:

```
$page = include_once "templates/page.php";
```

I put the "templates/page.php" under /sites/all/modules/front and Drupal complains about file missing. Any suggestion where best to put up the files to be included?

Then, after installing the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, I wrote the following

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
```

and was complained for Class 'simple_html_dom' not found. I have tried duplicating the library file to the same folder and home, but all cases not working. How to set up the correct path?

Many thanks.

Comment: I find that if I put the include file in the home directory (where Drupal installed), that always works. I suppose that's not a good practice though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## How to include some file?

### Method 1

You could place file anywhere under web-root folder which is folder with index.php file (home folder).

```
$type = 'module';
$name_of_module = 'custom_module';
$path = drupal_get_path($type, $name_of_module);
include_once($path . 'custom_file.inc.php');
```

The valid types are as listed:

- module
- theme
- profile
- theme_engine

Module name is the filename of .info file in modules folder.
[Read more about drupal_get_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/7)

### Method 2

To include file from existing module you should use:
    module_load_include('inc', 'content', 'includes/content.node_form');

## How to include template file?

Better place for template files is theme folder because others will expect templates files there.

[Read more about template naming suggestions.](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656)

But if this template has no sense without your custom module you could place this template file within custom module folder.

### To attach template in theme you should use:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook)     {
    if (array_key_exists('node', $variables)) {

         if ($variables['node']->type == 'article'){
            $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__article';
            }
    }
}
```

### To attach template in module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function MODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme,    $path) {
  return array (
    'node__CONTENTTYPE' => array (
      'variables' => array( . . . ),
      'template' => 'node--CONTENTTYPE' ,
      'base hook' => 'node',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'CUSTOM_MODULE'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Template file should be named node--CONTENTTYPE.tpl.php and placed under CUSTOM_MODULE folder.

[Read more about hook_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7)

**Do not forget to clear cache.**

Comment: Thanks. I think this is a very comprehensive answer. Nevertheless, I find that if I put the include file in the home directory (where Drupal installed), that seems always work by default without any additional declaration. Is that always true?

Comment: Sure, if you put file in home directory (where drupal installed) and used
`include_once "templates/page.php"; `
Why it works? Because path is relative to home directory. Try to add leading backslash ("/") to the path or move drupal to subfolder and this won't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `drupal_get_path` to get the full path of your file:

```
$page = include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'front') . 'templates/page.php');
```

[Here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/7) is the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The [Libraries API](https://www.drupal.org/node/1342220) provides this function.